# /build/include\caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h(4356): error : expected an identifier while compiling Caffe on windows

Tags: caffe

I am trying to port [Caffe-SSD](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd) to Windows. I moved all the new files (layers and whatnot) to the [Caffe's latest windows branch](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows) and used the Caffe_SSD `caffe.proto` file and initiated the compilation process. 
It seemed everything is in place but after several minutes of compilation it fails with these errors :

```
"C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
(CustomBuild target) ->
  C:/Users/Master/Desktop/Caffe/caffe-windows-ssd/build/include\caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h(4356): error : expected an ident
ifier [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:/Users/Master/Desktop/Caffe/caffe-windows-ssd/build/include\caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h(14835): error : expected an iden
tifier [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]

    414 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:08:49.15
ERROR: Build failed
```

Why am I getting this error? I used the very same caffe.proto from the ssd branch and therefore everything needs to be fine! where is the problem?
This is the configuration by the way :

```
 C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd>scripts\build_win.cmd
The system cannot find the drive specified.
The system cannot find the drive specified.
INFO: ============================================================
INFO: Summary:
INFO: ============================================================
INFO: MSVC_VERSION               = 14
INFO: WITH_NINJA                 = 0
INFO: CMAKE_GENERATOR            = "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"
INFO: CPU_ONLY                   = 0
INFO: CUDA_ARCH_NAME             = Auto
INFO: CMAKE_CONFIG               = Release
INFO: USE_NCCL                   = 0
INFO: CMAKE_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS    = 0
INFO: PYTHON_VERSION             = 3
INFO: BUILD_PYTHON               = 1
INFO: BUILD_PYTHON_LAYER         = 1
INFO: BUILD_MATLAB               = 0
INFO: PYTHON_EXE                 = "python"
INFO: RUN_TESTS                  = 0
INFO: RUN_LINT                   = 0
INFO: RUN_INSTALL                = 1
INFO: ============================================================
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PythonInterp: C:/Users/Master/Anaconda3/envs/anaconda35/python.exe (found suitable version "3.5.3", minimum required is "2.7")
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Boost version: 1.61.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   thread
--   filesystem
--   chrono
--   date_time
--   atomic
-- Found GFlags: C:/Users/Master/.caffe/dependencies/libraries_v140_x64_py35_1.1.0/libraries/include
-- Found gflags  (include: C:/Users/Master/.caffe/dependencies/libraries_v140_x64_py35_1.1.0/libraries/include, library: gflags_shared)
-- Found Glog: C:/Users/Master/.caffe/dependencies/libraries_v140_x64_py35_1.1.0/libraries/include
-- Found glog    (include: C:/Users/Master/.caffe/dependencies/libraries_v140_x64_py35_1.1.0/libraries/include, library: glog)
-- Found Protobuf: C:/Users/Master/.caffe/dependencies/libraries_v140_x64_py35_1.1.0/libraries/bin/protoc.exe (found version "3.1.0")
-- Found PROTOBUF Compiler: C:/Users/Master/.caffe/dependencies/libraries_v140_x64_py35_1.1.0/libraries/bin/protoc.exe
-- Found LMDB: C:/Users/Master/.caffe/dependencies/libraries_v140_x64_py35_1.1.0/libraries/include
-- Found lmdb    (include: C:/Users/Master/.caffe/dependencies/libraries_v140_x64_py35_1.1.0/libraries/include, library: lmdb)
-- Found LevelDB: C:/Users/Master/.caffe/dependencies/libraries_v140_x64_py35_1.1.0/libraries/include
-- Found LevelDB (include: C:/Users/Master/.caffe/dependencies/libraries_v140_x64_py35_1.1.0/libraries/include, library: leveldb)
-- Found ZLIB: optimized;C:/Users/Master/.caffe/dependencies/libraries_v140_x64_py35_1.1.0/libraries/lib/caffezlib.lib;debug;C:/Users/Master/.caffe/dependencies/libraries_v140_x64_py35_1.1.0/libraries/lib/caffezlibd.lib (found version "1.2.8")
-- Found Snappy: C:/Users/Master/.caffe/dependencies/libraries_v140_x64_py35_1.1.0/libraries/include
-- Found Snappy  (include: C:/Users/Master/.caffe/dependencies/libraries_v140_x64_py35_1.1.0/libraries/include, library: snappy_static;optimized;C:/Users/Master/.caffe/dependencies/libraries_v140_x64_py35_1.1.0/libraries/lib/caffezlib.lib;debug;C:/Users/Master/.caffe/dependencies/libraries_v140_x64_py35_1.1.0/libraries/lib/caffezlibd.lib)
-- CUDA detected: 8.0
-- Found cuDNN: ver. 6.0.20 found (include: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v8.0/cuda60/cuda/include, library: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v8.0/cuda60/cuda/lib/x64/cudnn.lib)
-- Added CUDA NVCC flags for: sm_61
-- OpenCV found (C:/Users/Master/.caffe/dependencies/libraries_v140_x64_py35_1.1.0/libraries)
-- Found OpenBLAS libraries: C:/Users/Master/.caffe/dependencies/libraries_v140_x64_py35_1.1.0/libraries/lib/libopenblas.dll.a
-- Found OpenBLAS include: C:/Users/Master/.caffe/dependencies/libraries_v140_x64_py35_1.1.0/libraries/include
-- Found PythonLibs: C:/Users/Master/Anaconda3/envs/anaconda35/libs/python35.lib (found suitable version "3.5.3", minimum required is "2.7")
-- Found NumPy: C:/Users/Master/Anaconda3/envs/anaconda35/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (found suitable version "1.13.1", minimum required is "1.7.1")
-- NumPy ver. 1.13.1 found (include: C:/Users/Master/Anaconda3/envs/anaconda35/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include)
-- Boost version: 1.61.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   python
-- Found Git: C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe (found version "2.10.1.windows.1")
--
-- ******************* Caffe Configuration Summary *******************
-- General:
--   Version           :   1.0.0
--   Git               :   unknown
--   System            :   Windows
--   C++ compiler      :   C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
--   Release CXX flags :   /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc
--   Debug CXX flags   :   /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc
--   Build type        :   Release
--
--   BUILD_SHARED_LIBS :   0
--   BUILD_python      :   1
--   BUILD_matlab      :   0
--   BUILD_docs        :
--   CPU_ONLY          :   0
--   USE_OPENCV        :   ON
--   USE_LEVELDB       :   ON
--   USE_LMDB          :   ON
--   USE_NCCL          :   0
--   ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK :   OFF
--
-- Dependencies:
--   BLAS              :   Yes (Open)
--   Boost             :   Yes (ver. 1.61)
--   glog              :   Yes
--   gflags            :   Yes
--   protobuf          :   Yes (ver. 3.1.0)
--   lmdb              :   Yes (ver. 0.9.70)
--   LevelDB           :   Yes (ver. 1.18)
--   Snappy            :   Yes (ver. 1.1.1)
--   OpenCV            :   Yes (ver. 3.1.0)
--   CUDA              :   Yes (ver. 8.0)
--
-- NVIDIA CUDA:
--   Target GPU(s)     :   Auto
--   GPU arch(s)       :   sm_61
--   cuDNN             :   Yes (ver. 6.0.20)
--
-- Python:
--   Interpreter       :   C:/Users/Master/Anaconda3/envs/anaconda35/python.exe (ver. 3.5.3)
--   Libraries         :   C:/Users/Master/Anaconda3/envs/anaconda35/libs/python35.lib (ver 3.5.3)
--   NumPy             :   C:/Users/Master/Anaconda3/envs/anaconda35/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.13.1)
--
-- Install:
--   Install path      :   C:/Users/Master/Desktop/Caffe/caffe-windows-ssd/build/install
--
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Master/Desktop/Caffe/caffe-windows-ssd/build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 9/16/2017 10:12:06 PM.
Project "C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
Project "C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (1) is building "C:\Users\Master\Desk
top\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\".
  Creating directory "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
CustomBuild:
  Checking Build System
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/Master/Desktop/Caffe/caffe-windows-ssd/build/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp
   is up-to-date.
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/Master/Desktop/Caffe/caffe-windows-ssd/build/src/gtest/CMakeFiles/gene
  rate.stamp is up-to-date.
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/Master/Desktop/Caffe/caffe-windows-ssd/build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/gene
  rate.stamp is up-to-date.
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/Master/Desktop/Caffe/caffe-windows-ssd/build/src/caffe/test/CMakeFiles
  /generate.stamp is up-to-date.
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/Master/Desktop/Caffe/caffe-windows-ssd/build/tools/CMakeFiles/generate
  .stamp is up-to-date.
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/Master/Desktop/Caffe/caffe-windows-ssd/build/examples/CMakeFiles/gener
  ate.stamp is up-to-date.
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/Master/Desktop/Caffe/caffe-windows-ssd/build/python/CMakeFiles/generat
  e.stamp is up-to-date.
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/Master/Desktop/Caffe/caffe-windows-ssd/build/matlab/CMakeFiles/generat
  e.stamp is up-to-date.
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/Master/Desktop/Caffe/caffe-windows-ssd/build/docs/CMakeFiles/generate.
  stamp is up-to-date.
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\ZERO_CHECK.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (default targets).

Project "C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (1) is building "C:\Users\Master\Desk
top\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
Project "C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj" (3) is building "C:\Users\Maste
r\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffeproto.vcxproj" (4) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "caffeproto.dir\Release\".
  Creating directory "C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\lib\Release\".
  Creating directory "caffeproto.dir\Release\caffeproto.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "caffeproto.dir\Release\caffeproto.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ComputeCustomBuildOutput:
  Creating directory "C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\include\caffe\proto\".
CustomBuild:
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/Master/Desktop/Caffe/caffe-windows-ssd/src/caffe/CMakeLists.txt
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/Master/Desktop/Caffe/caffe-windows-ssd/build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/gene
  rate.stamp is up-to-date.
  Running C++/Python protocol buffer compiler on C:/Users/Master/Desktop/Caffe/caffe-windows-ssd/src/caffe/proto/caffe.
  proto
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe /c /I"C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe
  -windows-ssd\build\include" /I"C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build" /IC:\Users\Master\.caffe\depend
  encies\libraries_v140_x64_py35_1.1.0\libraries\include /nologo /W3 /WX- /O2 /Ob2 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D NDEBUG /D CA
  FFE_VERSION=1.0.0 /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:
  inline /GR /Fo"caffeproto.dir\Release\\" /Fd"caffeproto.dir\Release\caffeproto.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue "C:\Us
  ers\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\include\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.cc"
  caffe.pb.cc
```

This is the content of `caffe.pb.h` line 4356:

```
  // nested types ----------------------------------------------------

  typedef ParamSpec_DimCheckMode DimCheckMode;
  static const DimCheckMode STRICT =
    ParamSpec_DimCheckMode_STRICT;
  static const DimCheckMode PERMISSIVE =
    ParamSpec_DimCheckMode_PERMISSIVE;
  static inline bool DimCheckMode_IsValid(int value) {
    return ParamSpec_DimCheckMode_IsValid(value);
  }
  static const DimCheckMode DimCheckMode_MIN =
    ParamSpec_DimCheckMode_DimCheckMode_MIN;
  static const DimCheckMode DimCheckMode_MAX =
    ParamSpec_DimCheckMode_DimCheckMode_MAX;
  static const int DimCheckMode_ARRAYSIZE =
    ParamSpec_DimCheckMode_DimCheckMode_ARRAYSIZE;
  static inline const ::google::protobuf::EnumDescriptor*
  DimCheckMode_descriptor() {
    return ParamSpec_DimCheckMode_descriptor();
  }
  static inline const ::std::string& DimCheckMode_Name(DimCheckMode value) {
    return ParamSpec_DimCheckMode_Name(value);
  }
  static inline bool DimCheckMode_Parse(const ::std::string& name,
      DimCheckMode* value) {
    return ParamSpec_DimCheckMode_Parse(name, value);
  }
```

and the line `14835`:

```
 typedef V1LayerParameter_DimCheckMode DimCheckMode;
  static const DimCheckMode STRICT =
    V1LayerParameter_DimCheckMode_STRICT;
  static const DimCheckMode PERMISSIVE =
    V1LayerParameter_DimCheckMode_PERMISSIVE;
  static inline bool DimCheckMode_IsValid(int value) {
    return V1LayerParameter_DimCheckMode_IsValid(value);
  }
  static const DimCheckMode DimCheckMode_MIN =
    V1LayerParameter_DimCheckMode_DimCheckMode_MIN;
  static const DimCheckMode DimCheckMode_MAX =
    V1LayerParameter_DimCheckMode_DimCheckMode_MAX;
  static const int DimCheckMode_ARRAYSIZE =
    V1LayerParameter_DimCheckMode_DimCheckMode_ARRAYSIZE;
  static inline const ::google::protobuf::EnumDescriptor*
  DimCheckMode_descriptor() {
    return V1LayerParameter_DimCheckMode_descriptor();
  }
  static inline const ::std::string& DimCheckMode_Name(DimCheckMode value) {
    return V1LayerParameter_DimCheckMode_Name(value);
  }
  static inline bool DimCheckMode_Parse(const ::std::string& name,
      DimCheckMode* value) {
    return V1LayerParameter_DimCheckMode_Parse(name, value);
  }
```

In case, full compilation log is needed, the complete log is [here](https://pastebin.com/Es9ax0CE)
This is the content of [caffe.proto](https://pastebin.com/WwJf3pYr) which I have used (copied from linux ssd) 
[Caffe.proto From caffe_ssd_linux](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/blob/ssd/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto)
[Caffe.proto From caffe-windows](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/windows/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto)

**Update 2:**

replacing `STRICT` with `_STRICT` and `PERMISSIVE` with `_PERMISSIVE` resulted in these errors :

```
"C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\annotated_data_layer.cpp(59): error C2039: 'PREFETCH_COUNT': is not a member of 'caffe::AnnotatedDataLayer<fl
oat>' [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\annotated_data_layer.cpp(60): error C2039: 'data_': is not a member of 'boost::shared_ptr<caffe::Batch<Dtype>
>' [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\annotated_data_layer.cpp(60): error C2228: left of '.Reshape' must have class/struct/union [C:\Users\Master\D
esktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\annotated_data_layer.cpp(104): error C2039: 'PREFETCH_COUNT': is not a member of 'caffe::AnnotatedDataLayer<f
loat>' [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\annotated_data_layer.cpp(105): error C2039: 'label_': is not a member of 'boost::shared_ptr<caffe::Batch<Dtyp
e>>' [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\annotated_data_layer.cpp(105): error C2228: left of '.Reshape' must have class/struct/union [C:\Users\Master\
Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\annotated_data_layer.cpp(157): error C2039: 'DistortImage': is not a member of 'caffe::DataTransformer<Dtype>
' [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\annotated_data_layer.cpp(161): error C2039: 'ExpandImage': is not a member of 'caffe::DataTransformer<Dtype>'
 [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\annotated_data_layer.cpp(168): error C2039: 'ExpandImage': is not a member of 'caffe::DataTransformer<Dtype>'
 [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\annotated_data_layer.cpp(183): error C2039: 'CropImage': is not a member of 'caffe::DataTransformer<Dtype>' [
C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\annotated_data_layer.cpp(229): error C2661: 'caffe::DataTransformer<Dtype>::Transform': no overloaded functio
n takes 3 arguments [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\annotated_data_layer.cpp(59): error C2039: 'PREFETCH_COUNT': is not a member of 'caffe::AnnotatedDataLayer<do
uble>' [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\annotated_data_layer.cpp(60): error C2039: 'data_': is not a member of 'boost::shared_ptr<caffe::Batch<Dtype>
>' [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\annotated_data_layer.cpp(104): error C2039: 'PREFETCH_COUNT': is not a member of 'caffe::AnnotatedDataLayer<d
ouble>' [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\annotated_data_layer.cpp(105): error C2039: 'label_': is not a member of 'boost::shared_ptr<caffe::Batch<Dtyp
e>>' [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\annotated_data_layer.cpp(157): error C2039: 'DistortImage': is not a member of 'caffe::DataTransformer<Dtype>
' [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\annotated_data_layer.cpp(161): error C2039: 'ExpandImage': is not a member of 'caffe::DataTransformer<Dtype>'
 [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\annotated_data_layer.cpp(168): error C2039: 'ExpandImage': is not a member of 'caffe::DataTransformer<Dtype>'
 [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\annotated_data_layer.cpp(183): error C2039: 'CropImage': is not a member of 'caffe::DataTransformer<Dtype>' [
C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\annotated_data_layer.cpp(229): error C2661: 'caffe::DataTransformer<Dtype>::Transform': no overloaded functio
n takes 3 arguments [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\detection_output_layer.cpp(65): error C3861: 'MapLabelToName': identifier not found [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\
Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\detection_output_layer.cpp(67): error C3861: 'MapLabelToDisplayName': identifier not found [C:\Users\Master\D
esktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\detection_output_layer.cpp(462): error C2039: 'TransformInv': is not a member of 'caffe::DataTransformer<Dtyp
e>' [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\detection_output_layer.cpp(462): error C2039: 'TransformInv': is not a member of 'caffe::DataTransformer<Dtyp
e>' [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\infogain_loss_layer.cpp(18): error C2039: 'axis': is not a member of 'caffe::InfogainLossParameter' [C:\Users
\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\infogain_loss_layer.cpp(57): error C2039: 'axis': is not a member of 'caffe::InfogainLossParameter' [C:\Users
\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\multibox_loss_layer.cpp(243): error C2039: 'GetNormalizer': is not a member of 'caffe::LossLayer<Dtype>' [C:\
Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\multibox_loss_layer.cpp(243): error C3861: 'GetNormalizer': identifier not found [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caf
fe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\multibox_loss_layer.cpp(249): error C2039: 'GetNormalizer': is not a member of 'caffe::LossLayer<Dtype>' [C:\
Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\multibox_loss_layer.cpp(249): error C3861: 'GetNormalizer': identifier not found [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caf
fe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\multibox_loss_layer.cpp(281): error C2039: 'GetNormalizer': is not a member of 'caffe::LossLayer<Dtype>' [C:\
Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\multibox_loss_layer.cpp(281): error C3861: 'GetNormalizer': identifier not found [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caf
fe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\multibox_loss_layer.cpp(322): error C2039: 'GetNormalizer': is not a member of 'caffe::LossLayer<Dtype>' [C:\
Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\multibox_loss_layer.cpp(322): error C3861: 'GetNormalizer': identifier not found [C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caf
fe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\multibox_loss_layer.cpp(243): error C2039: 'GetNormalizer': is not a member of 'caffe::LossLayer<Dtype>' [C:\
Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\multibox_loss_layer.cpp(249): error C2039: 'GetNormalizer': is not a member of 'caffe::LossLayer<Dtype>' [C:\
Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\multibox_loss_layer.cpp(281): error C2039: 'GetNormalizer': is not a member of 'caffe::LossLayer<Dtype>' [C:\
Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\multibox_loss_layer.cpp(322): error C2039: 'GetNormalizer': is not a member of 'caffe::LossLayer<Dtype>' [C:\
Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\video_data_layer.cpp(70): error C2039: 'PREFETCH_COUNT': is not a member of 'caffe::VideoDataLayer<float>' [C
:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\video_data_layer.cpp(71): error C2039: 'data_': is not a member of 'boost::shared_ptr<caffe::Batch<Dtype>>' [
C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\video_data_layer.cpp(71): error C2228: left of '.Reshape' must have class/struct/union [C:\Users\Master\Deskt
op\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\video_data_layer.cpp(80): error C2039: 'PREFETCH_COUNT': is not a member of 'caffe::VideoDataLayer<float>' [C
:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\video_data_layer.cpp(81): error C2039: 'label_': is not a member of 'boost::shared_ptr<caffe::Batch<Dtype>>'
[C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\video_data_layer.cpp(81): error C2228: left of '.Reshape' must have class/struct/union [C:\Users\Master\Deskt
op\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\video_data_layer.cpp(70): error C2039: 'PREFETCH_COUNT': is not a member of 'caffe::VideoDataLayer<double>' [
C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\video_data_layer.cpp(71): error C2039: 'data_': is not a member of 'boost::shared_ptr<caffe::Batch<Dtype>>' [
C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\video_data_layer.cpp(80): error C2039: 'PREFETCH_COUNT': is not a member of 'caffe::VideoDataLayer<double>' [
C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\src\caffe\layers\video_data_layer.cpp(81): error C2039: 'label_': is not a member of 'boost::shared_ptr<caffe::Batch<Dtype>>'
[C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Caffe\caffe-windows-ssd\build\src\caffe\caffe.vcxproj]

    1618 Warning(s)
    48 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:12:50.35
ERROR: Build failed
```

Comment: Could you add line #4356, #14835 of caffe.pb.h to the question? Lets see what the compiler complains about.

Comment: Can you try to change STRICT and PERMISSIVE in caffe.proto (it appears twice) to _STRICT and _PERMISSIVE and see if it helps? (Probably other source files should be changed as well, but it's interesting to see whether caffe.pb.h will compile - STRICT is a reserved word in Windows.

Comment: @rursw1: doing that resulted in 57 errors!

Comment: Of course, as you'll have to change all STRICT references to _STRICT. It shouldn't be many changes though.

Comment: @rursw1: You mean in all source codes and corresponding headers? !

Comment: Yes... This is what worked for me. It's ugly, I know, but it works - you can see if the compilation of caffe.pb.cc succeeded. If it did, this is your issue, and changing the headers / sources would work. If it didn't it's something else.

Comment: @OK, let me try and see if its the case. Thank you by the way , I report back the outcome when its done

Comment: @rursw1: Those errors are gone now, but new ones poped up! I updated the question with errors. whats wrong here?

Comment: This is really odd. Can you please update the full compilation log?

Comment: @rursw1: here is the full log : https://paste.ee/p/pFTvc

Comment: No idea... Maybe this PR could help: https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/pull/631

Comment: Thanks for your time and help anyway

Comment: I am having the same issue. Is there any update ?

Comment: I gave up on that. and went Pytorch!

Answer (score 2):

I was having the issues that you had in **Update 2** and with a bit of luck and googling I was able to solve them. So here it goes for the ones suffering from them,

I found [this](https://github.com/gustavla/autocolorize/issues/7) thread on GitHub which says,

- `PREFETCH_COUNT` should be changed to `prefetch_.size()` in every troubling cpp file under `<CAFFE_DIR>\caffe\src\caffe\layers`. In your case they should be `annotated_data_layer.cpp` and `video_data_layer.cpp`.
- `this->prefetch_[i].` should be changed to `this->prefetch_[i]->` in every troubling cpp file under `<CAFFE_DIR>\caffe\src\caffe\layers`. In your case they should be `annotated_data_layer.cpp` and `video_data_layer.cpp`. This will solve errors related to `label_': is not a member`, `data_': is not a member` and `left of '.Reshape' must have class/struct/union`
- For `infogain_loss_layer.cpp(18): error C2039: 'axis': is not a member of caffe::InfogainLossParameter` error, you need to add `axis` to `InfogainLossParameter` message in `caffe.proto` file. In my case last used id was 1, so I added it as `optional int32 axis = 2`; Now `InfogainLossParameter` message is like below,

```
message InfogainLossParameter {
  // Specify the infogain matrix source.
  optional string source = 1;
  optional int32 axis = 2;
}
```

Sadly, I don't think this will solve all your issues, the ones related to `DataTransformer` will remain but I hope it will help someone to fix some of them without spending as much time as I did.